# How to get actual position of Cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to organize favourites in my app. I have a database with three columns:

```
_id | name  | description |  star

1    London   some desc.
2    Berlin   some desc.    
3    Paris    some desc.     yes
```

I want to display favourites in listview. The refreshCursor() returns list of names with "star" column value "yes":

```
private static final String COLUMN_STAR = "star";

private void refreshCursor() {
        stopManagingCursor(cursor);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String TABLE_NAME = intent.getStringExtra("tableName");

        cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, COLUMN_STAR + " = ?",
                new String[] { "yes" }, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(cursor);
    }
```

It's ok.

Then after I click on `Paris` I send extra string with clicked position:

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String entryID = new Integer(position).toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(FavouritesActivity.this, ViewFavsActivity.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("elementId", entryID);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

But I get position (of `endtryID`) `0` and `ViewFavsActivity` displays decription of `London`.

How to get actual position of `Cursor` and send it to `ViewFavsActivity`?
Help, please.

---

Part of `FavouritesActivity` (onCreate): // method refreshCursor is above

```
refreshCursor();
String[] from = new String[] { COLUMN_NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvText };

    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor,
            from, to);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String entryID = String.valueOf(id);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(FavouritesActivity.this, ViewFavsActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("elementId", entryID);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Part of `ViewFavsActivity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // opening DB

        refreshCursor();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    setTitle = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_DESC },
            null, null, null, null, null);

    int entryID = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("elementId"));

    setTitle.moveToPosition(entryID);
    titleText.setText(setTitle.getString(setTitle
            .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESC)));

    }

    private void refreshCursor() {
        stopManagingCursor(cursor);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_STAR, COLUMN_DESC },
                "_id = ? AND star = ?",
                new String[] { intent.getStringExtra("elementId"), "yes" },
                null, null, null);
    }
```

---

**Added:**

[FavouritesActivity](http://pastebin.com/kSiX5W5G) on pastebin

[ViewFavsActivity](http://pastebin.com/7MkQWiRK) on pastebin

[Project](http://www.2shared.com/file/OcgoUda7/SSCCE.html)

Comment: I am happy to help you, but I don't see the problem right off. It will help a lot if you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which duplicates your problem. That way I can compile and run it for myself.

Comment: @Code-Guru Where can I upload it?

Comment: It should be small enough that you can copy and paste it into your question. Click the edit link at the bottom of your original post.

Comment: @Code-Guru I've added links to full activities. Please, look.

Comment: Please read the SSCCE link I gave above. For one thing, the code needs to be Self Contained. This means that you need to provide everything necessary to compile the program. In this case, I will also need the XML files for your layouts. Also, try to simplify it as much as possible so that the code isn't too long. Narrow your code down to exactly reproduce the problem without having any extra stuff from your original app.

Comment: @Code-Guru added link to eclipse project

Comment: Please read [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: @Code-Guru I read it. But I don't understand what should I do. So need I to upload xml of my layouts and code of activities? Xmls don't contain any necessary information, everything is in two activities. Please, write what should I do?

Comment: The idea is to create a small and simple program that recreates your problem. Make it as small as possible without any code which is unrelated to your question. One of the reasons we ask you to do this is so that we can compile and run the program ourselves. This is why the XMLs are necessary. We cannot compile the app without them.

Comment: @Code-Guru So the problem is solved. Thanks for the time you spent. But I didn't understand what SSCCE is because I upload a project that contains only code to solve this problem. You just needed to copy it to eclipse and run.

Comment: I guess I should have specified that I don't have Eclipse. Also, we typically like to have code posted here. That way it is available for future visitors in case the links you gave become invalid.

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad to hear that you solved the problem. Good luck with your Android development!

Comment: @Code-Guru I had to think about it. I'll keep this in mind. Good luck to you too!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Being a future visitor, your request was absurd. You wanted self-contained code to compile and test, but didn't even have the compiler. `cursor.getPosition()` is the position of the cursor and the `OnClickListener` could also be moved to the adapter to use the position of the cursor relative to the view through its own `position` value. Really basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that you are using two different Cursor's. You get `position == 0` from:

```
cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, COLUMN_STAR + " = ?",
            new String[] { "yes" }, null, null, null);
```

But then ask for position `0` in:

```
setTitle = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_DESC },
            null, null, null, null, null);
```

So the odds are good that you will get a different result.
*Also* Bundle can hold any primitive data type and a few more complex ones. So you don't need to convert a number into a String and then back to its original data type...

A **safer** approach is to use the row's id, so use this in your `OnItemClickListener`:

```
b.putLong("elementId", id);
```

And in `ViewFavsActivity`:

```
long entryID = bundle.getLong("elementId");
setTitle = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_DESC },
            "_id = " + entryID, null, null, null, null);
```

(Note: when in doubt *always* use `?` and `query()`'s `selectionArgs` parameter to prevent SQL injection attacks, but you are working with a `long` that you retrieved as an index, so you're safe in this context.)

Comment: Thanks for that, but now I got `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1` on line with `titleText.setText(setTitle.getString(setTitle
    .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESC)));` (Please, look link to ViewFavsActivity on pastebin).

Comment: No need, it's a common error. Cursor's start at index `-1`, you need to call `cursor.moveToFirst()` _before_ trying to read a value from the Cursor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to solve this problem for some hours and you made this in a short time. Also thanks for information about `putLong`.

Comment: No trouble. By the way, I'm giving you an upvote just for knowing how to read your Logcat and providing the error in your first comment. (I'd give you another for the slick table, but alas one vote per user...)

Comment: Thanks again =) The ability to use Logcat is the part of a successful development.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that your Cursor only result one object. I belive is londe, is it correct ? If yes. Always the position result in the list view is added a element more one. Ex:

If the list view have only one object:

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //Here will be showed the 0 position, not 3 like you whant.
            String entryID = new Integer(position).toString();
        }
    });
```

the solution:

You need to cast a view in the method to your Object placed in the Adapter. Ex:

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //Here will be showed the 0 position, not 3 like you whant.
            MyObject object = (MyObject)view; //This object is placed in the Adapter.
            object.getId(); //This method is inserted in my object or you can Override the method    toString() to return the id of your query.

            //Now you can send your ID to another Activity.

            //Put your code here.

        }
    });
```

It´s this. I hope that I help you with my solution. Any question please put your question here.

--

thiago L. Silva

Comment: Cursor returns only one object because there is only one `yes` value in `star` column. It returns `Paris`. But what `MyObject` is?

Comment: This Object was placed in your Adapter. The argument View view in method onItemClick return your Object placed in your Adapter. You can get him making a cast to your Object placed in your Adapter. Did you understood why the position came 0 ?

Comment: How did you construct your Adapter in this ListView ?

Comment: I understand why the position is 0. Adapter contains only 1 item and so position. Added links to full activities. Please, look.